# Playorm gradle build not finding jar files and failing on Mac with Play 2.2

Tags: playframework, playorm

I am trying to build Playorm from -https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm.
however the build is failing and I do not know why.  I looked in to the script file to see how APP_HOME was set but it seem the code may not be working.  I also notice that the build script has set the path to Gradle 1.6, I am using Gradle 2.0, however I couldn't find the reference in the script

thanks in advance

```
/usr/bin/gradle-2.0/bin ls
total 24
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 sazabo  staff  5070 Jul  1 09:52 gradle
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 sazabo  staff  2394 Jul  1 09:52 gradle.bat

/src/playorm-master ./gradlew build
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/sazabo/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.6-bin/72srdo3a5eb3bic159kar72vok/gradle-1.6-bin.zip.lck (No such file or directory)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/sazabo/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.6-bin/72srdo3a5eb3bic159kar72vok/gradle-1.6-bin.zip.lck (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:236)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:49)
    ... 3 more
~/src/playorm-master
```

Comment: Check out `build.gradle` (last lines) and `playorm/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`. The gradle version is mentioned there.

Comment: Thanks Tom, that is a help still getting exceptions will dive deeper

Comment: there is still a issue with the file location

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/sazabo/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.0-bin/34ooqmq1urnnhvpv2dlmidjcrc/gradle-2.0-bin.zip.lck (No such file or directory)